# Enabling location services for Exposure Notification Availability Alerts

Tags: ios

California finally rolled out an Exposure Notification app for iOS. I turned it on, but there’s a setting for “Availability Alerts” that I can’t enable because it says Location Services is turned off in Settings. Thing is, it’s not. Every other app on my phone is able to use Location Services. I can’t see any disabled app or service that might be relevant to Exposure Notifications.

[image]

On my buddy’s phone, it’s enabled. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "Availability Alerts" to be enabled, I believe you need to have 3 settings turned on:

- Location Services
- Location Alerts
- Significant Locations

It looks like you might not have "Significant Alerts" turned on.  Go to `Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services -> System Services` and turn that on.

[image]

Image courtesy of [MacObserver](https://www.macobserver.com/tips/how-to/see-where-apple-tracks-you-iphone-ipad/).

Comment: I did notice that was off (not sure why), and I did turn it on; didn't realize that's what finally made the Availability option available. Not sure why anyone would intuit that. Thanks!